# Laravel validation numeric with gte:1 throws exception

Tags: laravel, validation

Why Laravel throws

> `InvalidArgumentException('The values under comparison must be of the same type');`

exception, when input non-numeric text like 'test' on rule:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'account_no' => 'required|numeric|gte:1'
    ];
}
```

When expected just not to pass validation and display message:

`account_no field must be numeric`

How to solve this exception?

Comment: are you passing an integer? you might need to convert it to integer

Comment: No not integer. i was testing what if user passes non numeric value

Comment: https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/24650

Comment: please explain the gte:1 in your validation??

Comment: @InzamamIdrees greater than 0

Comment: For greater than 0, you have to use `min:1`

Comment: Yeah min:1 solves the problem. I was curious why numeric rule did not take action first

Comment: @merdan it probably did validate the numeric first, but laravel test all the rules before throwing the validation errors. The `bail` rule will stop the field validation on the first error though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Merdan the field under `gte` validation must be greater than or equal to the given `field`. The two `fields` must be of the same type.

example let's say you have two fields

```
POST DATA
// $request->comparison = 1;
// $request->account_no = 20319312;
```

your rules should be something like

```
return [
    'account_no' => 'required|numeric|gte:comparison'
];
```

Comment: As additional information would be to use `'required|numeric|min:1'` instead
And I guess that `integer` would be better than `numeric` for an `account_no`

Comment: @Demonyowh So for gte rule we have to define comparison field, not just give number. That is the reason exception is being thrown right?

Comment: yea .. the value should be from another field

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `gte`, the `gt` and `gte` are added in Laravel 5.6 and latest versions and I'm not sure what laravel version you are using.

I think you can **try** like this:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'account_no' => 'required|numeric|min:1'
    ];
}
```

**OR**

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'account_no' => 'required|numeric|min:0|not_in:0'
    ];
}
```

The `min:1` is the minimum value of 1 and no negative values are allowed
The `not_in:0` is the value cannot be 0.

Also you can also use `regular expression` for doing this job.

I hope it would be helpful. Thanks